# Django-Filters : override method to allow property's model filtering

Tags: python, django, django-filter

This is a model containing some field and a property `carbs_g_secured` :

**Models.py**

```
class Food(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ingredients_label = models.TextField()
    moisture_g = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def carbs_g_secured(self):
        # If moisture is missing
        if self.carbs_g :
            return self.carbs_g,'Carbs provided'
        else :
            return None, 'Moisture is missing'
```

I'd like to do some min/max filtering with `django-rest-framework` on the the `carbs_g_secured` property. I know I can't do that directly with `Django-filters` but I try to override the whole thing.

I have the following approach :

**Serializers.py**

```
class FoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    carbs_g_secured = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Views.py**

```
class FoodFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    carbs_g_secured_max = django_filters.NumberFilter(method='MyPropertyFilter')
    class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = {'name': ['exact', 'in', 'startswith'],
                  'species':['exact'],
                  'protein_g':['exact','lte','gte'],
                  'carbs_g_secured_max':['exact']}

    def MyPropertyFilter(self, queryset, name, value):
        results = [row for row in queryset if value and row.carbs_g_secured()[0] and row.carbs_g_secured()[0] < value]
        return results
```

Problem is this is returning a `list` where it's expecting a `query set`.

> web_1  | AssertionError: Expected 'FoodFilter.carbs_g_secured_max' to
>   return a QuerySet, but got a list instead.

So it seems I'm a bit stuck. I think it's not good practise to transform this list into `query set`.

What do you guys think ?
Am I heading the good way ? I have 20 others similar properties I want to filter against. I'm even considering converting all of those property into model fields. They are all the results of reasonable calculus made with the original fields from the food model.

How can I successfully manage to do this filtering and deal with the format expectation ?

Comment: Unclear, What's min/max filtering with respect to that property?

Comment: The `MyPropertyFilter`exemple is showing a max filtering. We set a value considered as a maximum (i.e max) . We retrieve all of the item which are showing a value of `item.carbs_g_secured()`  below this max. Same story with a minimum (min). The min/max is not related to the property, it's just the logic of filtering. I could have said : `lte` or `gte`